# Undefined variable in my Codeigniter View

Tags: php, codeigniter

Having trouble with displaying my data from controller in View.

Searched for this, tried few things and still not working for me.

My controller:

```
public function microBitcoin()
{
    $arr = array('hashtag' => 'myhashtag', 'tweet_id' => '673899616799191040');
    $data = array();
    $data['liczba_tweetow'] = $this->load->library('Twetterclass', $arr);

    $this->load->view('micro_btc', $data);
}
```

My View:

```
 <?php print_r($data); ?>

 <?php echo $data['$liczba_tweetow']; ?>
 //tried with $data->liczba_tweetow;
```

I still get the same error:

> > A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/micro_btc.php

How I can display this variable in my View?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like this,

```
print_r($liczba_tweetow);
```

see [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) for more information

Comment: When I use `print_r($liczba_tweetow);` its printing all my CI_Loader Objects. When I just echo variable `echo $liczba_tweetow; ` I get `Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string

Filename: views/micro_btc.php`

Comment: you are assigning here `$data['liczba_tweetow'] = $this->load->library('Twetterclass', $arr);`, so you are getting that.

Comment: So what I supposted to do to display this data in View?

Comment: you are loading the library to variable, so its printing what ever is returned from library.

Comment: My library supposted to return only a single intiger. When I use print_r I get all of CI_Loader Objects. My library `Twetterclass` is working very well without framework, so I why I just can't get in return what I supposted to get? I get the error: `Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string Filename`.

Comment: Is ther the required index in the returned array??

Comment: Hmm, dont know about it. My library class return a count of tweets:         `$n = count($json->statuses);

return $n;` and it works standalone

Comment: before return try `echo $n`

Comment: When I tried `echo $n`, it actually displayed $n in View, but in very beggining of template, not in place like `echo $liczba_tweetow;` or `print_r($liczba_tweetow);`. How I can fix this?

Comment: Controller: [Controller](http://pastebin.com/PTekE6w1) My library class: [Class](http://pastebin.com/wmPucwXj) and View: [View](http://pastebin.com/sLu5jx87)

Comment: since you have echoed in library, its coming in top.

Comment: When I echo in controller, it works just like echo in class. When I try to pass $n to view: `$data['liczba_tweetow'] = $n;` it shows same error in view: `Undefined variable`

Comment: what is line number 26??

Comment: it's: `$data['liczba_tweetow'] = $n;`

Comment: What is $n in controller??

Comment: in controller, `echo $this->load->library('Twetterclass', $arr);`, try that

Comment: error: `Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97307/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-michal-lipa).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php echo $liczba_tweetow; 
       print_r($liczba_tweetow);
  ?>
```

This is proper way to get data in view.

[Reference](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

your view should be look like this

```
<?php
 print_r($liczba_tweetow); 
?>
```

instead

```
<?php print_r($data); ?>

 <?php echo $data['$liczba_tweetow']; ?>
 //tried with $data->liczba_tweetow;**strong text**
```

when we load a view with the data the it would we converted in variable in respective key so you would get "$liczba_tweetow" instead $data['$liczba_tweetow']

Answer (score 0):

please follow this,in controller

```
public function microBitcoin()
{
$data['first'] = 'this is first';
$data['second'] = 'this is second';
$this->load->view('micro_btc', $data);
}
```

In view ,you can catch as like

```
echo $first;
//it will print this is first
echo $second;
//it will print this is second
```

Comment: Then I get another error: `Severity: 4096 Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string Filename: views/micro_btc.php`